# Template <class T> , "Error: .... does not name a type"

Tags: c++, templates, types

hello I have a problem with a template. I want a pointer stack using templates but I get the error "does not name a type". I have two classes, one that manages a stack of nodes and the other one is a node class. The problem is in the node class and I don't know how to resolve it. Could somebody explain to me how I should create a node object using a template decleared in another class. The code is below.

```
    template<class T> class PointerStack
    {
    public:
        PointerStack();
        bool isEmpty();
        bool push(T dataIn);
        bool pop();
        bool top(T &topItem);
        void clear();
        void print();
    private:
        int counter;
        Node<T>* start;
};

template<class T>
class Node
{
    public:
        Node(T dataIn);
        Node(T dataIn, Node vorigeIn);
        T getData();
        Node* getPrevious();
    private:
        T data;
        Node* previous;
        Node* next;
};


template<class T>
PointerStack<T>::PointerStack()
{
    counter == 0;
}

template<class T>
bool PointerStack<T>::isEmpty()
{
    if(counter == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

template<class T>
bool PointerStack<T>::push(T data)
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        start = new Node<T>(data);
        counter++;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Node<T> dummy = start;
        start = new Node<T>(data, dummy);
        counter++;
        return true;
    }
}

template<class T>
bool PointerStack<T>::pop()
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        Node<T> dummy = start;
        start = start->vorige;
        counter--;
        delete dummy;
        return true;

    }
}

template<class T>
bool PointerStack<T>::top(T &topItem)
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        topItem = start.getData();
        return true;
    }
}

template<class T>
void PointerStack<T>::clear()
{
    while(isEmpty())
    {
        pop();
    }
}

template<class T>
void PointerStack<T>::print()
{
    Node<T> dummy = start;
    if(!isEmpty())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            std::cout<<dummy->getData();
            dummy->v;

        }
    }
}

template<class T>
Node<T>::Node(T dataIn)
{
    data = dataIn;
    previous = NULL;
    next = NULL;
}

template<class T>
Node<T>::Node(T dataIn, Node previousIn)
{
    data = dataIn;
    previous = previousIn;
    next = NULL;
    previousIn->volgende = this;

}

template<class T>
T Node<T>::getData()
{
    return data;
}

template<class T>
Node<T>*  Node<T>::getPrevious()
{
    return previous;
}
```

and this is the error message:
[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: You need to declare `template<class T> class Node;` just before the definition of the template class `PointerStack`. Then `PointerStack` will know that `Node<T>` is a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You PointerStack class doesn't know of the Node class. You need to forward declare your Node class before declaring PointerStack:

```
template<class T>
class Node;
/* Your code goes here */
```